# Firebase rules - permission denied in orderBy query even though 'get' request works (REST)

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using Python and the REST API for querying firebase. I want to query my database by a field called 'my_friend_id'. Here are my rules:

[image: rules]

I'm able to get the friend id of any user without being authenticated using a get request to `/$uid/my_friend_id` but when I try to order by `$uid`s by `my_friend_id` I get a permission denied. I want to figure out someones lengthy `uid` using a short `my_friend_id`.

It seems like my permission is denied because my `orderBy="my_friend_id"` query is rejected by the top level rules at `/`, but I want it to be allowed based off of my rules in `/$uid/my_friend_id`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be able to read  from the root, you must have a `.read` rule on the root that allows the read. It seems you only want to allow a certain query, in which case you need to have rules that allows that query. See the documentation on secure queries for more on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Got it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated and thanks for working on such a great project :)

Comment: Good to hear. For future posts, please don't post screenshots of textual content. Instead post the actual text, so that it can be searched, and copy/pasted. You can use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to highlight it.

Comment: Good advice, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to incorporate a new rule at the root (`/`) level of the database that relates to queries. See the highlighted line in the image of my new rules. More info in the link of Frank van Puffelen's comment on my question.[image]

Make sure to include authorization features if your data should be secure!